# linux perf: x86: is the cache-misses event accuracy in per-process counting?

Tags: x86, perf

On the Intel x86 system, the 'cache-misses' event is mapped to LONGEST_LAT_CACHE.MISS, which counts core-originated cacheable requests that miss the L3 cache (Longest Latency cache). Since L3 cache resides in the uncore and uncore PMU is shared by all cores, then how does perf count the miss for a specific process?

For example, does below only count all L3 miss from process 'ls' or system-wide?

```
$ perf stat -e cache-misses -- ls
```

Comment: Easy enough to test: write a simple loop that doesn't access memory, and run it at the same time as a memory-intensive test program.  You could even pin them to separate logical cores of the same physical core.  It should count only L3 misses from the process you're profiling.  I assume the CPU internals involve the load response (received by the core) including a status code which says whether it hit or missed in L3.

Comment: Do you mean that this event is counted by CPU core PMU but not uncore PMU? If so it make sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to confirm it.  `perf list` on my Skylake lists `longest_lat_cache.miss` as a CPU event, not an uncore event.  Uncore event names all start with `unc_`